# How to impose a lexicographic order on an (arbitrary) POD C++ struct?

Tags: c++, reflection, lexicographic, lexicographic-ordering

I have some POD `struct foo`; suppose it's `struct foo { int x; unsigned y; }`. I want to be able to compare `struct foo`'s using lexicographic order - by order of their fields of course. That is, I want all of the operators <, ==, >, etc. to work for `struct foo`'s

Can I do this in some generic way, without having decorated my structure definition with any [reflection voodoo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11748131/1593077) - and without just spelling out all those operator definitions? Or is the ability to do this too much of a "language reflection dependent" expectation?

Comment: You can't just have a non-member, non-friend operator overload? That sounds best for what you want to do.

Comment: Standard c++ doesn't support _reflection_ (yet).

Comment: And with the sheer complexity of C++, I think it will be hard to add in a way that is comprehensively useful.  As an alternative, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40564415/120163

Comment: Is it okay if you have to list the relevant member names at the point where you name or use the comparison?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: No, I just want to be able to say `if (foo_1 < foo_2) { do_stuff(); }`

Comment: @TheEyesightDim: Why do we need friendship here? It's a struct, everything is public.

Comment: @IraBaxter:  +1 on the link to information about PTSes; but that would be a last recourse, quite possibly worse than just spelling out the comparison operators. At any rate, it seems this _is_ doable, without adding more features beyond C++17, so...

Comment: @einpoklum: I never mentioned needing friendship.

Comment: @TheEyesightDim: Well, it doesn't matter now, the gurus have shown us the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in C++1z. Basing on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39779537/2456565) answer, I prepared the following proof of concept:

```
struct anything {
    template<class T> operator T()const;
};

namespace details {
template<class T, class Is, class=void>
struct can_construct_with_N:std::false_type {};

template<class T, std::size_t...Is>
struct can_construct_with_N<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>,
        std::void_t< decltype(T{(void(Is),anything{})...}) >>:
                                                             std::true_type
{};
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
using can_construct_with_N=details::can_construct_with_N<T, std::make_index_sequence<N>>;

namespace details {
template<std::size_t Min, std::size_t Range, template<std::size_t N>class target>
struct maximize: std::conditional_t<
    maximize<Min, Range/2, target>{} == (Min+Range/2)-1,
    maximize<Min+Range/2, (Range+1)/2, target>,
    maximize<Min, Range/2, target>
>{};

template<std::size_t Min, template<std::size_t N>class target>
struct maximize<Min, 1, target>: std::conditional_t<
    target<Min>{},
    std::integral_constant<std::size_t,Min>,
    std::integral_constant<std::size_t,Min-1>
>{};

template<std::size_t Min, template<std::size_t N>class target>
struct maximize<Min, 0, target>:
    std::integral_constant<std::size_t,Min-1>
{};

template<class T>
struct construct_searcher {
    template<std::size_t N>
    using result = ::can_construct_with_N<T, N>;
};

template<class T, std::size_t Cap=4>
using construct_arity = details::maximize< 0, Cap, details::construct_searcher<T>::template result >;

template<typename T>
constexpr auto tie_as_tuple_impl(std::integral_constant<size_t, 1>, T&& t){
    auto&& [a] = t;
    return std::tie(a);
}

template<typename T>
constexpr auto tie_as_tuple_impl(std::integral_constant<size_t, 2>, T&& t){
    auto&& [a,b] = t;
    return std::tie(a,b);
}

template<typename T>
constexpr auto tie_as_tuple_impl(std::integral_constant<size_t, 3>, T&& t){
    auto&& [a,b,c] = t;
    return std::tie(a,b,c);
}

template<size_t S, typename T>
constexpr auto tie_as_tuple(T&& t){
    return tie_as_tuple_impl(std::integral_constant<size_t, S>{}, std::forward<T>(t));
}

}

template<typename T>
constexpr auto tie_as_tuple(T&& t){
    constexpr size_t S = details::construct_arity<std::decay_t<T>>::value;
    return details::tie_as_tuple<S>(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

Now, you can use `tie_as_tuple` to create a tuple that has all the operators you asked for already defined, in the way you asked for.

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nindDb4On3ODIDng)

Note that I had to prepare several overloads of `tie_as_tuple_impl`, one for each number of elements in a struct, but that scales linearly for the number of struct elements.

---

In C++14 there's [`magic_get`](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get) that could allow similar solution, but it has its caveats, see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abdeAew3gmQ) for more information.

Comment: This is taking me a while to decipher, but +1 already for the type trait which "counts" the number of elements in the struct - I still can't believe that actualy works... Also, nitpick: it's "arity" rather than "airity".

Comment: @einpoklum that part is stolen from Yakk's implementation (linked). I thought it was a typo too, but at this moment I'm busy seeing if I can make this work with structs with defined constructors (right now this is getting 0 and failing miserably, despite `can_construct_with_N<T,2>` returning true type).

Answer (score 2):

> Can I do this in some generic way, without having decorated my structure definition with any reflection voodoo - and without just spelling out all those operator definitions?

No, there's no way to achieve such in a generic way with the current c++ standard.

I don't even know what you mean with *"reflection voodo"* since the standard doesn't support type reflection (yet).

And even if so in future, I have doubts that operations like *list in lexicographical order* would be available in first place.

---

> Or is the ability to do this too much of a "language reflection dependent" expectation?

Probably yes. You may try with a language like c#, wich has reflection, it'll still be tricky to provide a generic operator implementation though.

Comment: By "reflection voodoo" I meant something like a vector of field names to field addresses or something that C++ reflection packages use.

Comment: Also, for shame, suggesting I blaspheme by switching to C# :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no shortcut for something like

```
auto operator < (const foo &a, const foo &b) {
    return std::tie(a.x, a.y) < std::tie(b.x, b.y);
}
```

in standard C++ (and in Boost afaics).

As this is indeed needless and error-prone typing, [Defaulted comparison operators](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3950.html) have been proposed, but not yet added to standard C++ (as of the current draft for C++17).

Comment: ... but that snippet in itself works, right? That's already an improvement, actually.

Comment: @einpoklum Yeah, the snippet itself is fine.

Answer (score 1):

As of C++20, it can be done simply by adding a defaulted spaceship-operator to the class,

```
struct foo
{
    //...

    auto operator<=>(foo const&) = default;
};
```

I guess that anyone interested knows that by now, but nevertheless it might be useful as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in standard C++11 or C++14.

You could consider having some program or script generating both the concerned `struct`-s and their compare function. Perhaps use some external preprocessor like [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) or [m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html) (or write your own C++ generator). [Qt `moc`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/why-moc.html) might be inspirational.

Or you might consider having some compiler plugin (if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/): coded [in C++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html), or in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org); if using [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/): coded [in C++](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangPlugins.html)) to help the job. That would require perhaps several weeks of work (because C++ compilers are very complex beasts) so is worthwhile only for large programs.

Comment: I didn't even know GCC supported plugins, actually. Interesting.